# SSRS 2008 - how do I add a child group in the middle of the parent?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Probably something obvious I'm missing, but I'm trying to create a child row group within an existing row group that spans four rows, but I want the child group to be between rows 3 and 4 of the parent group and should itself only span 1 row.

In the image below the red arrow shows where I want to create a 1 row (repeating) subgroup for 'Department'.

[image]

The final output should be:

```
DESCR
  Headcount by Major
    Department1
    Department2
    .
    .
  Major to Faculty Ratio
DESCR2
  Headcount by Major
    Department3
    Department4
    .
    .
  Major to Faculty Ratio
```

However, when I attempt to add a child group (no matter where I do it from) it creates the child group at the top row (as in the image below)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on top of the cell where your Department group is, and select Insert Row - Outside group, shifting the location of the inner group to the position you want.

(That doesn't exactly solves your problem, but it let's you put the group on the position you want)

Comment: Well - basically ended up just recreating tablix, making sure to start with all of the innermost groups first.  Seems odd that I can't arbitrarily place a child group anywhere but the very top row.  Joao, sounds like your answer was basically the same, both require a bunch of rework (if I did as you suggested i would then have to shift all of the labels, cell expressions, etc. around anyway)